# How can I abort a running JDBC transaction?

Tags: java, jdbc

Is there a way to prematurely abort a transaction? Say, I have sent a command to the database which runs five minutes and after four, I want to abort it.

Does JDBC define a way to send a "stop whatever you are doing on this connection" signal to the DB?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As mentioned by james, [Statement.cancel()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#cancel()) will cancel the execution of a running Statement (select, update, etc).  The JDBC docs specifically say that Statement.cancel() is safe to run from another thread and even suggests the usage of calling it in a timeout thread.

After canceling the statement, you're still stuck with the job of rolling back the transaction.  That is *not* documented as being safe to run from another thread.  The [Connection.rollback()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#rollback()) should happen in the main thread doing all the other JDBC calls.  You can handle that after the canceled Statement.execute...() call completes with a JDBCException (due to the cancel).

Comment: Here is oracle-specific behaviour on calling `Statement.cancel()`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/659063/603516

Answer (score 17):

I am guessing what you want to do is prevent your application blocking on long running queries / transactions. To this end, JDBC supports the concept of a query time out. You can set the query timeout using this:

```
java.sql.Statement.setQueryTimeout(seconds)
```

And handle the `SQLException` thrown by the `execute()` method by rolling back the transaction (of course, that would only work if you have autocommit set to false, and your JDBC driver supports Statement.cancel()).

Comment: I think this is a better and simpler approach, since it allows the tread to "clean itself", versus having an outside thread do it (which always involves a new set of issues).

Answer (score 8):

Check out Statement.cancel().

Answer (score -5):

No, you can't abort it using standard JDBC.

You might try to check if your particular RDBMS define some extension to suppot it.

Comment: I've had vendors tell me this.  If a particular JDBC driver doesn't implement Statement.cancel(), that's a quality-of-implementation problem.  It's there and documented for that use case.