# struts2 long polling with jquery

Tags: java, jquery, struts2, long-polling

I have previous experience doing a long polling with PHP and jQuery that check for new chat messages.

The Idea was to have a while loop that checks if there are new messages, if yes, then returns the new message, if no then sleep for 5 seconds and check again.

I would like to do the same using java struts2 framework.  I created an action class that has a while loop, does the same, and use Thread.sleep() for the wait.

However I experience some very high CPU usage.  Am I doing it right?  I apologize that I do not ave any sample code right now because I re-did it using a simple approach that uses client-side polling.

Help appreciated.

Comment: On the previous occasion, did you achieve long polling without incurring high server load? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If (despite the title saying jQuery), you want to do this in Java (*"I would like to do the same using java struts2 framework."*), then [a while loop is not a good solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390242/java-while-loop-and-threads);

Instead, you should use a [java.util.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) ( / [TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html)).

Please note that in Struts2 one Action is instantiated for every request, so if you create a Timer in the Action, and you have 100 concurrent users, you have 100 timers running.
It would be better to [use it from an EJB](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tejb_timerserviceejb_enh.html).

Take a look at this SO answers too:

1) [Timer & TimerTask versus Thread + sleep in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453295/timer-timertask-versus-thread-sleep-in-java)

2) [How to set a timer in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044726/how-to-set-a-timer-in-java)

and at the Javadoc:
[The Java EE 5 Tutorial - Using the Timer Service](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html)

My 2 cents...

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a BlockingQueue?  I don't undestand why this has anything to do with jQuery and long polling.  This is a server internals design problem.