# Cancel execution a big query on oracle submitted by SQLDeveloper

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Perhaps, this is a naive question. When we use SQLDeveloper to execute a big query to Oracle, the we cancel the task. I wonder if it helps to cancel the execution of the server or not?

Thanks,

Comment: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9714932&#9714932

Answer (score 2):

yes, in case the DB server finds the time to handle the protocol message, it cancels the execution of the statement and returns an 
*ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation* instead of an SQL result set.

Comment: Thanks BertNase. Do you have any reference for this?

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01013_user_requested_cancel_of_current_operation.htm

Comment: Exactly the same thing done programmatically in own code seems to be discussed in this Question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/656162/702599

Comment: I am not sure because I haven't tested it and there is no explicit document of SQLDeveloper saying that. Of course, it is nearly 99% that the answer is correct.