# Cancel Long Running Query in JDBC with Tomcat Connection Pool

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling

We have a reporting app that can run long queries. The user is allowed to cancel a running report by clicking a button. This calls a method that stops the reporting thread and closes its JDBC connection.

A problem we are facing is that the JDBC connection is returned to the tomcat pool but it is still in use. So when another thread gets this connection and tries to use it, the execution is blocked in the Oracle driver by the abandoned statement.

It seems like a fix would be to first call the statement.cancel() method, but some have pointed out (http://stackoverflow.com/a/659063/603516) that this method might not have immediate effect.

So what is the right approach? Can I close the connection without returning it to the pool? Should I leave it unclosed? I know there are some timeout settings I could set on the connection, but since it is a reporting application the queries have the potential of running for a few hours and I don't feel comfortable putting any kind of timeout.

Maybe one option could be to set a validationQueryTimeout? But what if the connection is not validated before every use?

```
> "Report_Worker-26" Id=104 in RUNNABLE (running in native)
>     at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
>     at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
>     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
>     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
>     at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:311)
>     at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:105)
>     at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:305)
>     at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:249)
>     at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:171)
>     at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:89)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:123)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:79)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineStream.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineStream.java:426)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:390)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:566)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:215)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:58)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:776)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:897)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1034)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3820)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3867)
>       - locked oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@60e36e18
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1502)
> ...
> 
> "http-bio-9050-exec-17" Id=205 in BLOCKED on
> lock=oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@60e36e18
>      owned by Report_Worker-26 Id=104
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.createStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:3878)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.validate(PooledConnection.java:453)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.validate(PooledConnection.java:394)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:775)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:619)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:188)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:128)
```

Comment: A connection will return to the pool when explicitly close or commit is called.You can try adding a final block and try to close/commit the connection there so that the connection is successfully returned to the pool

Comment: cancel can not be immediate, especially when there is a translation to be rolled back. Usually when you use sane connection pool, calling close() on proxy connection class, will return it into the pool. Also connection pool implementation should guarantee, that you do not borrow a connection having active transaction on it.

Comment: @user06062019, this is not the issue, my connection is being returned to the pool but is still having an active statement running.

Comment: @loopkin you can set the validationQueryTimeout and a validateQuery which will be used when you specify the other settings like testOnBorrow,testWhileIdle and testWhenReturn.This can be a potential solution but it does not seems clean (this can be subjective though :-))

Comment: @user06062019, yes, for this app it might be an acceptable solution to force queryValidation for every connection borrow as we should not have that many connections. I was hoping for a cleaner solution, but this would work. Thanks!

Comment: one more note: the cancel command should be thread safe, you should be able to call it from any thread. The blocked thread should be released after some time, then it catches an exception with error "ORA-01013 user requested cancel of current operation". PS: use at least JDBC drivers ver 12.2 to use this feature. And also there should not be a VPN between client and server.

Comment: @ibre5041, thanks for the info. I think my driver is older than this, I'll check if I can upgrade it.