# Statement.cancel() and its thread-safety guarantee(s)

Tags: java, jdbc, thread-safety, prepared-statement, specifications

Unfortunately, the jdbc specification remains silent about the guarantees of `Statement.cancel()`.

The only thing which is stated by the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#cancel%28%29) is that `Statement.cancel()` is [thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295920/how-can-i-abort-a-running-jdbc-transaction). 

But:

- Is it guaranteed that `cancel()` will always work?
   (in a manner that the thread which is currently executing the `Statement` will immediately unblock and continue)
- Is it guaranteed that `cancel()` will not block and (more or less) return immediately?

Comment: At least for the oracle jdbc driver there are no such guarantees - especially in case of network or server-side issues: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/apxtblsh.htm#BACDAICJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it guaranteed that cancel() will always work?

No. At least not in my experience. I think I even had to deal with drivers that simply threw an UnsupportedOperationException

> Is it guaranteed that cancel() will not block and (more or less) return immediately

No. Depending on the statement being executed, sometimes the cancel() might wait until the first row of a query is returned. Again this is highly dependent on the driver.

Comment: Is it possible to set a timeout for the cancel process to kill the process rigorously? I thought about a `Statement.cancel(int timeout)` method, but I didn't find one ;)

Answer (score 2):

From the same javadoc:

> if both the DBMS and driver support aborting an SQL statement

That limits the guarantee. The other limitation is that `Statement.cancel()` is implemented by the concrete driver, in other words, the implementation is not part of the Java RE.

So cancelling really *should* be thread safe, but you'll have to ask the vendor of your actual driver/DBMS.