# How to clean cancel execution of a heavy SQL in the middle of executing?

Tags: java, sql, multithreading, jdbc

There are two threads of execution, one is the thread that connects via JDBC and executes a heavy query, something like this:

```
Statement stmtData = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
ResultSet rsData = stmtData.executeQuery("SELECT * from hugeTable");
```

and the second is the one which starts the first mentioned thread and of course cancels it if requested by user, let's say in the middle of executing query by DBMS which might take a long time.

I tried calling interrupt() method of first thread in the second one, hoping it would throw InterruptedException in the first one, but it didn't.

So how to cancel the execution of the query **quick and clean**?

Comment: Can you please give the actual usecase you are trying to achieve ? Based on the usecase i can suggest the solution that suits your scenario.

Comment: @Subba my actual usecase is like the "Break" button in PL-SQL Developer, you know, while a SQL is executing in background the user still can cancel it. the problem is that the stmtData.executeQuery() method is not asynchronous so I don't know how to break it's execution. any suggestion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I abort a running JDBC transaction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295920/how-can-i-abort-a-running-jdbc-transaction)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your jdbc driver supports canceling, then you can use java.sql.Statement.cancel() method. The thread needs to catch the InterruptedException and then call cancel() on the statement that is executing.

Comment: how to make the thread to throw the InterruptedException? when I call thread.interrupt(); it doesn't throw any exception when it's executing the statement.

Comment: Ok Thanks @Jeff, it works, however I didn't have to throw an InterruptedException, the cancel method throw a SQLException itself.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to do this. I would use a connection pool and let my app-server to manage that though a DataSource y think this is the most common way to do it.

If you still want to hardcode it you can use the apache BasicDataSource and . setMaxWait();

If you still want to do it quick and dirty try using (not recommended besides is a deprecated method) threadQuery.Stop();

Comment: actually I think setMaxWait() is not the case, because I want the query execution to break as soon as the user hits the cancel button.