# H2 Database: Abort Query

Tags: sql, jpa, jdbc, h2

I have a long running select query on an embedded H2 Database and want to allow the user to cancel the query.

How can this be done? I cannot find anything about this.

[UPDATE]
To be more specific I'm running my query using JPA. How can the query be stopped?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I abort a running JDBC transaction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295920/how-can-i-abort-a-running-jdbc-transaction)

Comment: thanks for the hint. I'm running my query using JPA. So I don't have a statement which I can cancel. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: JPA provides no query cancel mechanism. Obviously if you were using JDO you could do that

Comment: ok, so if I want to stick to JPA, there is no chance of stopping a query prematurely? Perhaps there is a possiblity which is specific to the H2 database?

Comment: _Can_ you use the JDBC API?

Comment: Use it for what? I think I'm only restricted to JPA because I don't want to rewrite all my queries.

Comment: @Dirk You can cancel a query using JDBC, even if the query is not executed using JDBC. That's why I ask. But maybe it's the wrong approach - would a [query timeout](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#set_query_timeout) be better?

Comment: How is this query cancelling using JDBC done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

H2 supports a query [timeout setting](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#set_query_timeout). You can set this in the database URL as follows: `jdbc:h2:~/db/test;query_timeout=10000`. (Maybe this is not the right approach for you, but it might be for others that read this question.)

You can also cancel a query running in another connection (session) using the [`cancel_session` function](http://h2database.com/html/functions.html#cancel_session). But for this you need to enable the multi-threaded mode, which is currently not recommended for production use (it is still experimental in version 1.3.175).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a few queries which might take very long, then don't use JPA for them. Create your own statement so you can cancel it.

Alternatively, get the source code for a JDBC proxy like [log4jdbc](https://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/) and add code that allows you to get connections and statements per thread. That would allow you to get the statement after JPA has sent it to the proxy.