# How to stop ongoing java.sql.statement.executeQuery()?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, derby

I'm using latest derby10.11.1.1.
Doing something like this:

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver())
java.sql.Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:filePath", ...)
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
stmt.setQueryTimeout(2); // shall stop query after 2 seconds but id does nothing
stmt.executeQuery(strSql);
stmt.cancel(); // this in fact would run in other thread
```

I get exception `"java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Caused by: ERROR 0A000: Feature not implemented: cancel"`

Do you know if there is way how to make it work? Or is it really not implemented in Derby and I would need to use different embedded database? Any tip for some free DB, which I can use instead of derby and which would support SQL timeout?

Comment: Please show your actual code, rather than "something like" it.  It's difficult to diagnose the issue without the complete context.  Please read "[ask]"  for additional details.

Comment: h2 supports a query timeout: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21984515/217324

Comment: @DougR. my actual code is bit longer. What information are you missing? I'm afraid that Derby just does not support the cancel() at all. I found [reference manual page](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/ref/rrefexcept71493.html) where is written `cancel() not supported by the server.` So the questions remaining is how to un-lock derby query without cancel() or what else embedded database to use which can be cancel().

Comment: So if it doesn't violate any NDA's, post your actual code, or a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that causes the error.

Answer (score 1):

As i got in java docs

> void cancel() throws SQLException
>   Cancels this Statement object if both the DBMS and driver support aborting an SQL statement. This method can be used by one thread to cancel a statement that is being executed by another thread.

and it will throws

`SQLFeatureNotSupportedException` - if the JDBC driver does not support this method

you can go with `mysql`.
there are so many embedded database available you can go through 
[embedded database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database)

Comment: it seems that mysql would require to install mysql server separately. There seems to be no free embedded mysql. Am I right? My goal is to have one jar including DB itself.

Comment: yes you need to install server for mysql then you need different database as in wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database

Comment: But they don't say whether cancel() would be supported or not :(. BTW is there other way than `cancel()` to kill the dead-locked transaction? Or am I doomed forever when this happens and I need to close whole app?

Comment: as nathan tolds h2 supports. you can go with that.

Answer (score 1):

If you get `Feature not implemented: cancel` then that is definite, cancel is not supported.

From [this post by H2's author](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22005191/217324) it looks like [H2](http://h2database.com) supports two ways to timeout your queries, both through the JDBC API and through a setting on the JDBC URL.

Comment: Yup works - in H2 table lock timeout is by default and changable by `statement.execute("SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 5000");`

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found that there is deadlock timeout in derby as well only set to 60 seconds by default and I never have patience to reach it :).

So the correct answer would be:

`stmt.setQueryTimeout(2);` truly seems not working

`stmt.cancel();` truly seems not implemented

But luckily timeout in database manager exists. And it is set to 60 seconds. See [derby dead-locks](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.0/manuals/develop/develop75.html#HDRSII-CONCEPTS-16400).

Time can be changed using command:

```
statement.executeUpdate("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY(" +
                "'derby.locks.waitTimeout', '5')");
```

And it works :)