# How to close a transaction gracefully when stop a application JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am using transaction to move data from one place to another. Some tables are huge, I am tuning the application, but sometimes I don't want wait, I just kill the application. But the problem is that the query is already sent to the DB, although I kill my application(codes), the transaction(query) is not canceled. Is there any way to cancel or roll back the transaction when I kill my application?

I know that I can login to the DB server and kill the query. That's not the method I want to use. I am asking how to rollback or cancel the query in the codes when the application is killed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Statement.cancel()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295920/how-can-i-abort-a-running-jdbc-transaction) to cancel running statements. In a standalone Java application you can [register a shutdown hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) which is called when the Java VM is terminated to close the open statements.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
          public void run() {
              for (Statement s : list of running statements) {
                 s.cancel();
              }
          }
    });
```

Comment: Another quesiton, how can I get the list of running statements using jdbc?

Comment: I don't know offhand if there is an API for this or if you will have to maintain the list by yourself. I suggest posting a new StackOverflow question for this.